Fix a hole in wooden floor
My girlfriend stepped on one part of the wooden floor wearing heels and it made a hole. The wood seems very bad quality, I wouldn’t be surprised its cardboard.(it’s an airbnb).
What are some ways to fix it? Bear in mind that she would probably have to do it on her own. So the less complicated, the better.



I don't believe that is wood. It looks to be a plastic transition strip.  There is not practical way to repair it.  It will need to be replaced.  They are often available at the bigbox and flooring stores.

I would let the owners know so they can fix it properly.  If a heel puts a hole in it, it could cause foot/ankle/leg damage/harm.  Quite a few lawyers make stuff like this their whole business.  It is easy to replace like @RMDman says, but it should be better supported underneath.  Much cheaper for the owners to fix it right than have lawyers after them.

Yep. Get over the instinct to hide the damage. If the place didn't come with a "remove high heels before entering" warning this is a defect in the construction, not some malicious damage your girlfriend deliberately inflicted on the floor.

I just caught that the home was an AIRBNB.  Agree with the above comments. Bring it to the attention of the owners. It is more a liability for them than damage by you.

This might be like a once in a century flood, but in two years it might happen again, if not fixed right.  I do not have enough money for the second time and doubt most people do.

How'd she create the small hole that looks like the tip of a nail did it?

@Huesmann the small hole was already there.

@Dino how do you know?
